# No PHP/Smarty errors are logged after white screen

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, smarty, prestashop

Nothing is added into my `/var/log/php_errors.log` when the white screen occurs.

**Why the white screen doesn't return or log any errors**?

In my `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` I have:

 `display_errors = On`, `log_errors = On` `error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log`
`phpinfo()` returns the same values


 `/var/log/php_errors.log` does log some errors in other pages

In my `[Prestashop_dir]/config/defines.inc.php` I have `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);`

and in `smartyadmin.config.inc.php` I also added `$smarty->debugging = true;`

URL of the page that is causing the white screen:

```
[Prestashop_backend_url]/index.php?controller=AdminPdf&token=d10cf8b3819b0922610f36caf0e37c24&submitAction=generateDeliverySlipsPDF&id_order=1
```

`/var/log/apache2/access.log` returns 200:

```
31.178.202.67 - - [11/Aug/2015:05:15:46 -0400] "POST /trzmiel4/admin4708/index.php?controller=AdminProducts&token=f4f509fc075d49764138165e9c0e4c4a&id_product=286&action=Suppliers&updateproduct&ajax=1&rand=1439284549458 HTTP/1.1" 200 1381 "http://188.210.220.115/trzmiel4/admin4708/index.php?controller=AdminProducts&id_product=286&updateproduct&token=f4f509fc075d49764138$764138165e9c0e4c4a" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36"
```

but `/var/log/php_errors.log` **remains silent**

Comment: I've encountered this once or twice. Sometimes the error is so severe that it stop everything in its tracks. What I did was insert breakpoint into the program before I found the breaking point. It was some kind of PHP parse/fatal error which indeed does not log itself.

Answer (score 1):

this is causing due to the limit of memory, pls increase the value of memory_limit in your php.ini config file. Prestashop admin products page requires more memory since it loads all the product images (admin product thumbnail - if its the first time you are accessing the admin products it will try to generate the product thumb images)